# WCF Service rest error handling using WebFaultException

Tags: wcf, exception, bad-request

I need to handle the exception in **WCF Service application**.
But in the windows application I can't get the error message. It's only display as `Bad Request`.

In the WCF Service throw the following exception.

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>(string.Format("Invalid Client ID.", clientID), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your windows application (client), you have to catch the exception and get the detail of the error

```
try 
{
    client.YourServiceMethod();
}
catch (FaultException<string> ex)
{
    MessageFault messageFault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
    Console.WriteLine(messageFault.GetDetail<string>());
}
```